# Running go program on Google Cloud Run without listening for incoming HTTP requests

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I wrote a Go program which doesn't need to retrieve external http calls at all by default. I tried to deploy it on Google Cloud Run and received the following error:

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port
> defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this
> revision might contain more information.

I understand it happens because my code doesn't provide a port. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662223) states:

> container must listen for incoming HTTP requests on the port
> that is defined by Cloud Run and provided in the $PORT environment
> variable

My question is what can I do if wouldn't like define any ports and just want to run the same code I run locally? Is there an alternate solution to deploy my code without it, or I must add it anyway if I want run the code from Cloud Run?

Comment: Have you looked at Cloud Run Jobs?  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run#jobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For containers that do not require an HTTP listener (HTTP server), use Cloud Run Jobs.

- Cloud Run Jobs is in preview.
- Your Go program must exit with exit code 0 for success and non-zero for failure.
- Your container should not listen on a port or start a web server.
- Environment variables are different from Cloud Run.
- Container instances run until the container instance exits, until the task timeout is reached, or until the container crashes. Task timeout default is 10 minutes, max is one hour.

[Cloud Run - Create jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs)

Comment: I am seeing now the App Engine has a cron job feature as well. Possibly could you give me a hint that App Engine or Cloud Run's cron function should I pick?

Comment: @rihekopo -Please create a new question so that there is space for details. I would select Cloud Run.