# Deployment failed to start and listen on the port with nginx + php

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a problem with deploying to google cloud. I have a dockerfile which nginx and php8.1.
Locally, everything works as it should, but when I deploy on google cloud I get an error:
`The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT = 8080 environment variable.`
Service in google cloud is configured by default on port 8080.
I noticed that nginx without php builds normally and starts but with php doesn't work and gets this error like above.

dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine as nginx

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

FROM php:8.1-fpm AS php

COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            curl \
            libmemcached-dev \
            libz-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libjpeg-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libwebp-dev \
            libxpm-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            libonig-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
```

I added an `EXPOSE 8080` but it doesn't work with that either

nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/symfony/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' always;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;
        }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

I have read various posts on the stack overflow e.g. [Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662222/container-failed-to-start-failed-to-start-and-then-listen-on-the-port-defined-b)
but it doesn't solve my problem.
Any suggestions what I have wrong ?

In cloud logging i have this:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.",
  "insertId": "8f70f71c-fc36-4b7d-b903-25e9c770342f-2124",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "build_id": "8f70f71c-fc36-4b7d-b903-25e9c770342f",
      "build_trigger_id": "",
      "project_id": "adroit-sol-340313"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-10-19T11:01:20.973405245Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "build_step": "Step #2"
  },
  "logName": "projects/adroit-sol-340313/logs/cloudbuild",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-10-19T11:01:21.466513119Z"
}
```

Comment: Do you have details in theCloud Logging?

Comment: I added logs to the question

Comment: Nothing more? After or before in Cloud Logging? You have no clue here. And why do you use beta deploy command? Any specific requirement?

Comment: I tested on beta and forgot to change but previously tested without beta. 
Finally I changed my docker build and is currently building from richarvey/nginx-php-fpm image. 
Everything works now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As per @KrzysiekW, I tested on beta and forgot to change but previously tested without beta. Finally I changed my docker build and is currently building from richarvey/nginx-php-fpm image. Everything works now. Thanks for the help.