# Continuously deploy ASP.NET WebAPI from GitHub to Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-webapi, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

##### I need some help getting this to work. I've got it to the point where my container is built, but Cloud Run says the service isn't listening on the specified port.

### *Updated: 6/28/2023*

- Changed project to not use top-level statements, in order to have a Main method for entrypoint.
- Added cloudbuild.yaml to repo root (posted below)
- Updated Dockerfile to correct multiple issues (updated below)

  - Biggest problems were the copy commands and then specifying port to run on
- Latest status:

  - Builds successfully in Cloud Build, with default (for ASP.NET 6.0 WebAPI) output type of "Console Application"
  - Cloud Run still failing to start, but the logs reveal better details (posted below)

### Details:

Source code for my sample app, a simple ASP.NET 6.0 WebAPI with default WeatherForecast controller, can be found here: https://github.com/andre-engelbrecht/sample_net_api

**cloudbuild.yaml:**

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api'
      - '-f'
      - 'Sample_API/Sample_API.API/Dockerfile'  # Update the path to your Dockerfile
      - '.'  # Set the build context to the root directory
images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api'
```

**Dockerfile:** (*which builds successfully on CloudBuild*)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Sample_API/Sample_API.API/Sample_API.API.csproj", "Sample_API.API/"]
COPY ["Sample_API/Sample_API.API/", "Sample_API.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Sample_API.API/Sample_API.API.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/Sample_API.API"
RUN ls -a
RUN dotnet build "Sample_API.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sample_API.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=true

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
#Set the environment variable to listen on the specified port
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT  
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sample_API.API.dll"]
```

**Cloud Run complains of the following:**

```
The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable
```

[image: cloud run failed]

**Cloud Run Logs:**

```
- A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/'.
- Failed to run as a self-contained app.
- The application was run as a self-contained app because '/app/Sample_API.API.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
- If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/app/Sample_API.API.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

### Question:

What can I do to get this to work? I'm new to Docker and GCP, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong? And though there are many guides out there, I could not find one for my particular use case.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662223/4261155), the problem is that my service is not listening on the defined port (8080), but how/where do I specify what port it should listen on when in Cloud Run? Locally I've set it up so that it starts on port 8080, but that didn't fix GCP.

I followed the following guides to get this far:

- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core
- **ChatGPT - this honestly got me most of the way, finding relevant info on the web by myself is challenging on this subject**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: (1) Update the `EXPOSE` instruction in your Dockerfile to expose port 8080 instead of port 80.
(2) Modify the `CreateHostBuilder` method in your `Program.cs` file to make the application listen on port 8080.
(3) Ensure your Cloud Build configuration file includes the `--port=8080` flag in the `gcloud run deploy` command

Comment: With the help of ChatGPT I now feel much more confident about my Cloud Build setup and process. I believe the Cloud Run logs provide the best clues as to what's wrong here, but I don't know what to make of it yet. I've tried various options so far, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I finally got it all working!**

---

#### Core things I needed to add / change:

##### 1. Create (or alter) project without top-level statements

Initially I had (unknowingly) created my project with top-level statements, this meant that there was no "Main" method in Program.cs to use as an entry point.

##### 2. Include `cloudbuild.yaml` to define build and deploy steps

There's likely more then one way to do this, but I ended up adding a `couldbuild.yaml` file to the root of my repo to define build and deploy steps for Cloud Build.

###### This is what my `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api'
      - '-f'
      - 'Sample_API/Sample_API.API/Dockerfile'  # Update the path to your Dockerfile
      - '.'  # Set the build context to the root directory

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'sample-net-api'  # Update with your service name
      - '--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api'
      - '--region=us-central1'
      - '--platform=managed'
      # Additional deployment options go here

images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sample-api'
```

##### 3. Fix my `Dockerfile`

My `Dockerfile` has some errors, most notably the commands to copy the project- and other files to the `/src` directory during build.

I also added a 2nd project to my solution, a class-library to define core code and keep my controller lean. Which mandated further updates to make the COPY more generic.

###### This is what my `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# Copy all files to /src directory
COPY ["Sample_API/", "Sample_API/"] 
# "Navigate" to main project directory
WORKDIR "/src/Sample_API/Sample_API.API"
# Restore and build
RUN dotnet restore "Sample_API.API.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Sample_API.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
# Publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sample_API.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=true

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
# Set the environment variable to listen on the specified port
# Only used in load Docker test deployments - not used in Cloud Run
# ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT  
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sample_API.API.dll"]
```

##### 4. Start service on port defined by Cloud Run

Lastly I had to ensure my service started on the port that was specified in Cloud Run setup, to avoid the infamous `The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=$PORT environment variable` error.

I did this by adding the following to `Program.cs`:

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") != null)
{
    builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT")}");
}
```

*A big shoutout to ChatGPT, which when you ask the right questions, can indeed be very useful.*