# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'revision' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Container failed to start and listen on PORT=80

Tags: docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy my flask web application on gcp using cloud run.
It works fine locally but when I try to deploy it using gcloud I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'my-flask-app-00005-rof' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=80 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn  
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Then I follow these steps:

- Build docker file:

  ```bash
  docker build -t my-flask-app .
  ```
- Tag the image:

  ```bash
  docker tag my-flask-app europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/propane-nomad-396712/cloud-run/my-flask-app
  ```
- Push the tagged image to Artifact Registry:

  ```bash
  docker push europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/propane-nomad-396712/cloud-run/my-flask-app
  ```
- Deploy using gcloud:

  ```bash
  gcloud run deploy my-flask-app \
  --image europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/propane-nomad-396712/cloud-run/my-flask-app \
  --platform managed \
  --allow-unauthenticated
  ```

However I get the error mentioned above. Based on the things mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662222/container-failed-to-start-failed-to-start-and-then-listen-on-the-port-defined-b) I did the following:

- In my main.py file allow for incoming http requests:

  ```py
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)),host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
  ```
- Not specifing a specific port in the gcloud command

Unfortunately these things did not change anything.

Comment: Go to Cloud Logging and look at the error at startup. You will have more detail on what crash the container.

Comment: The log only tells me this aside from the message already mentioned in the terminal: ```terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /bin/sh: exec format error```

Comment: Why do you use a exec (I didn't mention it!)? Use gunicorn directly!

Comment: Because it is mentioned in this official example from google: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service

Comment: Hmm did you try without?

Comment: Tried without ```exec```but I get the same error in terminal and logs

Comment: You can't have an exec format error in the logs if you no longer use exec!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working. Turns out you need to specify `--platform linux/amd64` when building the docker image if you are on apple silicon macs otherwise you will get the following error in the logs when trying to deploy the image to cloud run: `terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /bin/sh: exec format error`.
I wish google would mention this somewhere in their docs/examples.

Full command to build the docker image:

```bash
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t my-flask-app .
```

Comment: That did the trick. My error was `terminated: Application failed to start: failed to load /usr/local/bin/flask: exec format error` but building for `linux/amd64` solved it