# simple docker image for python on MacOS doesn't run in Google Cloud Run -- exec format error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had a full python script which for days couldn't run in Google Cloud Run but worked fine locally.

I built a small test application and I get the following error in Google Cloud logs:

```
textPayload: "terminated: Application failed to start: failed to load /usr/local/bin/uvicorn: exec format error"
```

Running the container locally worked fine.

```
docker run -e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/sophia-db784/cloud-run-test:v1.1
docker build -t gcr.io/sophia-db784/cloud-run-test:v1.1 .
docker push gcr.io/sophia-db784/cloud-run-test:v1.1
gcloud run deploy cloud-run-test --image gcr.io/sophia-db784/cloud-run-test:v1.1 --platform managed
```

The console terminal displays:

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [cloud-run-test] in project [sophia-db784] region [us-central1]
X Deploying...
  - Creating Revision...
  . Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'cloud-run-test-00005-k78' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=sophia-db784&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/cloud-run-test/revision_name/cloud-run-test-00005-k78&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22cloud-run-test%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22cloud-run-test-00005-k78%22
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
```

I expected a container which runs successfully in local docker should work fine in Google Cloud Run.

This is the script:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World from FastAPI on Google Cloud Run!"}
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY . .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir fastapi uvicorn

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run Uvicorn when the container launches
CMD ["uvicorn", "cloud-run-test:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

My real script has **slightly** more complexity in that I need to access a secret in Google Secret Manager, and I spent a few days trying to debug and thinking that was the problem in terms of permissions.

But with this simple app, I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start)

> Note: If you build your container image on a ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, [build your image using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers#builder).

Also you can refer [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68766137/18265638) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035863/18265638) when building the docker image on macos

> build your Docker container with the `--platform linux/amd64` flag before deploying the image to Cloud Run

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t image-name:v1.1 .
```

Comment: Thank you @sathi -- I did use cloudbuild...but I did not use the command you shared, I used --platform managed.  Thank you, I'll try that now!

Comment: Super, thank you, I now have a "green" image, but there's a 404 I am debugging, which seems odd to me, but at least I no longer get the exec format start error....